# Application cannot be executed when launch from a different folder

Tags: powershell

I have a third party application that has following two files in **c:\sandbox** folder.

SomeApplication.exe
SomeApplication.ini

The executable uses the ini file for various configuration settings. When I run this executable from the powershell command prompt after change my directory to c:\sandbox, all works great.

```
PS C:\sandbox> SomeApplication.exe  
INFO: Its working great
```

However when I try to run same application without changing my directory to sandbox folder, it does not work.

```
PS C:\> .\Sandbox\SomeApplication.exe
ERROR: SomeApplication.ini could not be found
```

I try to do following before running the application

```
PS C:\> Set-Location -Path "C:\Sandbox"
```

But still get same error. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The program assumes that it will be launched from the current directory and looks for the ini file using windows apis that search the current direction and the path. If you add it to the path it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it didn't help

Comment: do you have the source

Comment: I can get it but the developer from that team has told me that application looks for ini file at the same location where executable is. Plus like I said when I cd into folder the folder where files are and launch the applcation, it works perfect

Comment: You can run a little test and put a link to the file using mklink in another directly and launch it from there.  

you can allso use Start-Process and set the working directory

Comment: I attempted to do a Start-Process and set the WorkingDirectory of ProcessStartInfo object to the sandbox folder. Get the same error.

Comment: _"the developer from that team has told me ..."_  I'd check the code!  It's not uncommon for devs to assume things work fine everywhere just because it works OK in their dev environment, which turns out to not match the real world.  Alternatively, you could use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see where the app is actually looking.  If you can't change the code or some other easy setting to get it to look in the 'right' place, one option is an [AppCompat](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7352) shim to re-direct it.